# I am trying to read Excel data using Apache POI

Tags: selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;


public void getDataFromExcel() 
    {
        File src = new File("C:\\Users\\kunalku\\Desktop\\Selenium\\Excel\\TestData.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet Sheet2 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    }
```

I am getting error like (The package org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel is accessible from more than one module: poi, poi.examples, poi.scratchpad)
I am rookie in selenium, so kindly help me regarding this.

Comment: How are you adding Apache POI to your classpath?

Comment: public static ArrayList<String> getDataFromExcel(int colnum) throws Exception  
 {
  File src = new File("C:\\Users\\kunalku\\Desktop\\Selenium\\Excel\\TestData.xlsx");
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  XSSFSheet Sheet2 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  Iterator<Row> rowIterator = Sheet2.iterator();
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (rowIterator.hasNext())
  {
   list.add(rowIterator.next().getCell(colnum).getStringCellValue());
  }
  return list;
  
  
 }

Comment: i am getting error in this line 
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = Sheet2.iterator();
as it says The package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel is accessible from more than one module: poi, poi.ooxml 
these 2 jars only i have added thru POI zip archive, as i am beginner in selenium kindly help me

Comment: *classpath* is what matters here - what jars did you add to your classpath?

Comment: I can see these three jar in my classpath :- curvesapi-1.04.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar and xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar . Do i need to add any jar here?Please help me to get out of this problem i am stucked here @Gagravarr

Comment: Why not [read the Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) and work out [based on the detailed instructions given](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components) what jars you need?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you added all the JARS available in **POI zip archive**. I will suggest please use only below JARS in your project build path configurations:

```
poi-<version>***.jar
poi-ooxml-<version>***.jar
```

Comment: But when i am adding this code to the existing code which i have pasted above
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = Sheet2.iterator();
and adding this packages import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
again it is showing error like "The package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel is accessible from more than one module: poi, poi.ooxml"
Can u suggest anything ?

Comment: @Kunal, Please accept the answer. You can try your code only with poi-ooxml-<version>***.jar
If still not working raise a new question, with proper screenshots. I will check the same once.